Move data in dataframe based on a value of a different column
I have a dataframe that looks like this:
Put/Call StrikePrice fixedprice floatprice fixedspread floatspread
Put          10           0         20           0           0
Put          10           0         20           0           0
nan           0           0          0           13          15
nan           0           0          0           14          16

If the put/call column has the value 'Put', I need to take the value from the strike price column and place it in the fixedspread column, and I need to take the value from the float price column and place it in the float spread column. Once the values are in the correct places I can get rid of the Put/Call column, strike price column, float price column and fixed price column. 
the output should look something like this:
  fixedspread floatspread
       10          20
       10          20
       13          15
       14          16


You can directly combine the columns with mask using the underlying numpy array for the right-hand side:
out = (df[['fixedspread', 'floatspread']]
       .mask(df['Put/Call'].eq('Put'),
             df[['StrikePrice', 'floatprice']].values)
      )

Output:
   fixedspread  floatspread
0           10           20
1           10           20
2           13           15
3           14           16


I should've mentioned, I have many other columns I need to be included in the output. Is there a different approach that would work?

@iBeMeltin can you be more explicit and give an example? You can always join the desired columns afterwards

There are like 20 total columns in the dataframe, the ones I provided is just a section of the whole dataframe, but I am only concerned with the columns I provided so I can get the necessary values in the correct columns

import numpy as np
conditions = [df[‘Put/Call’] == ‘Put’]
choices_fixedspread = [df[‘StrikePrice’]]
choices_floatspread = [df[‘floatprice’]]
df[‘fixedspread’] = df[‘fixedspread’] + np.select(conditions, choices_fixedspread, default=0)
df[‘floatspread’] = df[‘floatspread’] + np.select(conditions, choices_floatspread, default=0)
print(df[[‘fixedspread’, ‘floatspread’]])

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
